# WMT Change of Address not working

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, https

I have been asked by a client to install an ssl certificate on her website which I have done and all working well! I have sorted out the security plugin and the .htaccess file with correct 301 redirects.

All variations of the site automatically redirect to https://www.example.com
I have also added all the variations to GWT and set the preffered domains to www.example.com

However with all of this done I cannot use the change of address feature as it's just coming with no available sites. Have I missed something here?

Phillip

**UPDATE**
I thought it may be good to add a couple of screenshots showing my clients GWT account...
[image]

Here is the change address page for the site also to confirm I want the change of address to goto the https:// version...

[image]

Finally if I click on the add it now link on the above page I get this....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use change of address tool to migrate http to https version of website.

[Here is official reference webpage, says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en).

> The tool does not currently support the following kinds of site moves:
>   subdomain name changes, protocol changes (from HTTP to HTTPS), or
>   path-only changes.

This post from [john mueller](https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/PY1xCWbeDVC) might help you in future.

Comment: Thank you @goyllo have since found out buddy! Essentially it's the same so should not affect any seo!